# Knockout - Redirect to another page after a success ajax post on click binding

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

I'm facing a problem with redirecting the user to another page after posting to the server through an ajax request, I'v tried returning true to allow the default click action but the problem with this is that I don't know when my ajax request is going to complete and if it's going to be success or not due to it's assynchronous so it's posible that the browser redirects the user before data its saved.

Update #1
To be clearer, my problem is with window.location.replace(url GoTo) line on the complete callback function, I am not being redirected to anywhere, code works fine until this line, I have not got any errors on runtime. Also if I debug the code it works as I expect it do it except the redirection instruction that it is being totally ignored.

My click function looks like:

```
self.save = function (viewmodel, event) {
        var data = ko.toJSON(self);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: "/Titulo/Create/",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#messageContainer").html('<p><span class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></span> Guardando...</p>');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    $("#messageContainer").html('<p><span class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></span>¡Guardado con exito!</p>');
                } else {
                    $("#messageContainer").html('<p><span class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></span>¡Ha ocurrido un problema al procesar esta operación!</p>');
                }
            },
            error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#messageContainer").html('<p><span class="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse"></span>¡Ha ocurrido un problema al procesar esta operación!</p>');
            },
            complete: function (request, textStatus) {
                if (textStatus === "success") {
                    var host = window.location.host;
                    var urlToGo = host + "/Titulo/Index/";
                    window.location.replace(urlToGo);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope someone could help me or at least give me an idea.

Comment: The code in the success/complete functions of your ajax call are there to handle the asynchronous part of the ajax call. Those functions will not fire until the ajax call is complete. Can you provide more information on what you're actually experiencing instead of the desired outcome? Are there errors? Does the address in the address-bar get changed?

Comment: I have no problem with the ajax request, it's working right but for some reason this window.location.replace(urlToGo) line is not working, nothing happens, just data is saved as expected and the application stay just there the user click the button save without redirect to the url specified on the complete callback function. I tested the same code of my function using jquery click event handler and it works perfectly also the window.location.replace(urlToGo) line so I think the problem of redirection is related with the knockout click binding but I haven't got any solution yet.

Comment: Try window.location.hash ?